# How to create a bootable hard disk image from an iso image?

Tags: boot, virtualbox, iso, udf

I would like install a proprietary operating system onto my CentOS box using VirtualBox. There is a problem though, when I mount the install ISO image as a DVD, soon the installer complains of missing DVD drivers. I tried to download some but they did not work.

Now I want to circumvent the DVD issue and I would like to create a virtual disk image of the install ISO. The forum discussion

[ISO To VDI VBoxManage convertfromraw Not Bootable](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=37765)

says that

> I am trying to make a bootable vdi from a bootable ISO 
>   for linux guest. I am running
>
> VBoxManage convertfromraw source.iso output.vdi
>
> I get a valid vdi that I can attach and read but I cannot 
>       boot from it. Any idea how to solve this.

for an experienced forum user says

> To use "convertfromraw" your starting point (as the name implies) 
>       has to be a raw image of a hard disk - which an ISO image 
>       most certainly is not.

In spite of this, is there a Unix way of creating a bootable hard disk image of a Windows 7 install disk? And, to create a .vdi file of that?

Comment: I've never tried this but you might be able to install from USB. Make a bootable USB and point your virtual machine to it.

Comment: I don't know virtualbox so what comes to my mind is: do you have control over the CD/DVD virtual driver type? Can you set for instance a virtual IDE or SATA driver type?

Comment: @Nasha I tried to use a virtual dvd driver as IDE and as SATA as well, did not work. Even when I created a bootable hard disk out of the iso and removed all the DVD drives it asked for DVD driver software. I'm afraid that proprietary company does not like the idea that I would use a legal college copy of their opsys inside VirtualBox. I remember from the old times -- middle of nineties -- when I tried to use their product: I remember these endless difficulties. No wonder that I use Linux since.

Comment: @Gergely I understand you very well indeed...

Answer (score 1):

Well this was better a VirtualBox and Windows issue.

I had an other Win7 virtual machine, I added a virtual disk. I copied the necessary files according to

http://www.instructables.com/id/Install-Windows-7-without-USB-or-DVD-without-upgra/

and made it bootable.

Then I created a new virtual machine whose sole disk was this newly created bootable drive.

I could then boot this new VM and the Win7 installation started.

This did not solve my original problem but this is an answer to my above question. Although not by Unix means but I was able to create a hard disk that boots the contents of the install DVD iso image.